# Line intersection with rectangle

Tags: matlab, line, intersection, rectangles

In matlab, how can I decide whether a line intersects with a rectangle or not ?

[image: Lines and rectangle]

For example the upper line is not intersecting with the rectangle and the two lower ones do,

**Then:** How can I decide the existence of the intersection from knowing two points of the line and another two points from the rectangle ?

My work:

**Way 1:** I am trying to solve the two equations of the line and the diagonal of the rectangle then check the solution point if it's within the rectangle or not.

Comment: I've tried some trigonometric calculation, I will prepare them then append them to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The line and rectangle intersect if the line intersects with any side of the rectangle. All you need is a line/line intersection algorithm. For help with that, try searching here or elsewhere on the net.